# Python 2.7 If middle_name is null print something else print something else

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to build an online MASH game. How do I output:

print "Welcome to the program {} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name) if no middle name is entered but:

print "Welcome to the program {} {} {}".format(self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name) if a middle name is entered:

class Name (object):

```
def __init__(self, first_name='', last_name='', middle_name=''):
    if not first_name:
        first_name = raw_input("What is your first name: ")
    if not last_name:
        last_name = raw_input("What is your last name: ")
    if not middle_name:
        middle_name = raw_input("What is your middle name[Leave blank if not applicable]: ")
        if middle_name == '':
            print "No middle name here!"
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.middle_name = middle_name
    self.print_name()

def print_name(self):
    if not middle_name:
        print "Welcome to the program {} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
    else:
        print "Welcome to the program {} {} {}".format(self.first_name,
                                                   self.middle_name,
                                                   self.last_name)
```

chris = Name()

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want the program to output something different if the middle_name raw input is not entered

Comment: If you make the `middle_name` parameter default to `None` in the `__init__`  method, (`def print_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name=None):`) your code seems to do what you are describing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the behavior you're describing:

```
class Name (object):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, middle_name=None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.print_name()

    def print_name(self):
        if not self.middle_name:
            print "Welcome to the program {} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
        else:
            print "Welcome to the program {} {} {}".format(self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name)

chris_jones = Name(first_name='Chris', last_name='Jones')
chris_taylor_jones = Name(first_name='Chris', middle_name='Taylor', last_name='Jones')
```

Notice I only added the `None` parameter to your `__init__()` method. `middle_name=None` supplies a default value, in case the caller doesn't supply a `middle_name` parameter. [This syntactic feature is called a "keyword argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333937/python-how-key-is-passed-into-the-function-with-default-value-of-none#comment75671753_44333937).

output:

```
Welcome to the program Chris Jones
Welcome to the program Chris Taylor Jones
```

Comment: Awesome! This did what i needed. Thank you